# Bulk update statement for numeric pattern

Tags: oracle, bulkupdate

I have a table `TXN_METHOD` with a column `TXN_MTHD_CODE` that currently has values from `TXN_MTHD_1` to `TXN_MTHD_35`.

How can I perform a single bulk update statement that changes the numeric pattern to

```
TXN_MTHD_001
TXN_MTHD_002
......
TXN_MTHD_035
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TXN_METHOD SET TXN_MTHD_CODE = 'TXN_MTHD_' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(TXN_MTHD_CODE, '[^0-9]', ''))), 3, '0') WHERE TXN_MTHD_CODE LIKE 'TXN_MTHD_%';
```

Above is my solution, the suffix changed to start from 001 to 035.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your method to:

```sql
UPDATE TXN_METHOD
SET    TXN_MTHD_CODE = 'TXN_MTHD_'
         || LPAD(SUBSTR(TXN_MTHD_CODE, LENGTH('TXN_MTHD_') + 1), 3, '0')
WHERE  TXN_MTHD_CODE LIKE 'TXN_MTHD_%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE txn_method (txn_mthd_code) AS
  SELECT 'TXN_MTHD_' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 35;
```

Then, after the `UPDATE`, the table contains:

| TXN_MTHD_CODE |
| --- |
| TXN_MTHD_001 |
| TXN_MTHD_002 |
| TXN_MTHD_003 |
| ... |
| TXN_MTHD_033 |
| TXN_MTHD_034 |
| TXN_MTHD_035 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-g8Mvj7H)